# Python: Replacing character in for loop

Tags: python

I want to remove the "." character. When I use this

```
text = "Rmyname.lastname@mail.com"
text = (text.replace('.',' '))
head, sep, tail = text.partition('@')
print(head)
```

It works and this is the output: `Rmyname lastname`

But when load an external file and read every line, its doesnt replace the "." character.

```
with open('found.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
        head = (row[0].replace('.', ' '))

        head, sep, tail = row[0].partition('@')
        print(head)
```

This is the output: `Rmyname.lastname`

How can i solve this?

Comment: @DYZ in a csv reader `row[0]` would be value of the first column

Comment: @rdas True, I did not notice it was a csv reader.

Comment: row[0].partition('@') change this to head.partition('@')

Answer (score 2):

You store the result of the replacement into the variable `head`. The original `row[0]` still has the period. Change `row[0].partition('@')` to `head.partition('@')`.